# Trying to authenticate users with Passport.js and Soundcloud

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, soundcloud, passport.js

I am trying to make a web app in NodeJS, that uses `passport` to authenticate users. I've incorporated Soundcloud in my app on the front end, but would like to add soundcloud authenication in as well. I've tried many packages, and `passport-soundcloud` is the one that has seemed to work the best. However, somewhere along the line, and the stack trace won't tell me where (location in the `passport-soundcloud` code), I get this error:

```
TokenError
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/Users/marisusis/Documents/Repos/visualizer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:329:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/Users/marisusis/Documents/Repos/visualizer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:376:16)
    at /Users/marisusis/Documents/Repos/visualizer/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
    at /Users/marisusis/Documents/Repos/visualizer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18
    at passBackControl (/Users/marisusis/Documents/Repos/visualizer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/marisusis/Documents/Repos/visualizer/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this, or an alternate package or method I could use?

Comment: It looks like there's a problem parsing the response from SoundCloud. Are you able to see any details on the HTTP response or code that's being returned?

Comment: Sam let me check